# Calculating average intensity of area with matlab regionprops

Tags: matlab, pixel, area

I have a grayscaled picture, where there are some objects with different shapes.
Also i have binary image of this grayscaled picture.

With MajorAxesLength and MinorAxisLength ratio (from regionprops) i can identify each of them, but how i can calculate average intensity each of that objects?

And is it possible to calculate average intensity of lines, that gives MinorAxisLength and MajorAxisLength?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to `regionprops` the `'PixelIdxList'` handle. Then you can do the following:

```
s = regionprops(BW,'PixelIdxList');
for n=1:numel(s)
     meanI(n)=mean(image(s(n).PixelIdxList));
end
```

this assumes that `BW` is the binary image and `image` is the grayscale one.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. But is it possible to calculate average intensity of lines, that gives MinorAxisLength and MajorAxisLength?